# Issue with error in hosting my application

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am trying to deploy a project visual studio 2015 project in IIS 8 and I get the following error :

> hosting_error
>
> The target framework in the `<compilation>` element of the web.config
>   file is used only to target version only to 4.0 and later of the .NET
>   framework (for example `<target framework="4.0">`. The target
>   framework currently references to a version that is later than the
>   installed version of the .NET framework. Specify a valid version of
>   the .NET framework, or install the required version of .NET framework.

My .NET version is 4.5.2. So, how can I solve this issue. Please help me in this. Should I install VS 2015 in my server where the IIS 8 resides. I have checked the App_pools, They are targeted to 4.0 version. Please help me in this.

Comment: install 4.5.2 on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS, The Application pool version need to be changed from 2.0 to 4.0. That will solve the Issue.